# Boundedness of Riesz transforms.

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

The Riesz $R_i$ transform on $\mathbb{R}^n$ is defined by 
$$ R_if(x)= \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \frac{t_i-x_i}{\vert x-t \vert^{n+1}}f(t) dt$$
for a Schwartz function $f$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Can you please tell me, how can one show that they admit a bounded extension on $L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$?

Comment: Using the Fourier transform and the Plancherel identity is the quickest way for this particular question, but more generally I would recommend Stein's book "Singular integrals and differentiability properties of functions" for the relevant theory for singular integrals such as the Riesz transforms.

Comment: @nicolas You could write an answer. 